# Dragon Age Inquisition: Xbox 360 controls

Tags: xbox-360, dragon-age-inquisition

My friend has inquisition for Xbox One and we played it together. I only have an Xbox 360 and was super excited when I found out they'd made a version for 360 too. My problem is that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to open the map on the 360 controller.

Answer (score 2):

It is in the middle of the Radial Menu (from [EA](http://help.ea.com/en/article/ea-help-guide-to-dragon-age-inquisition/)):

> If you get lost, the quest map is accessible in the middle of the radial menu layout.